# c#: print all fields of an empty protobuf message

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to print an empty protobuf message for gui to let user fill that message.
as my protobuf messages are nested, it is not practical to declare a descriptor for each message.

I want to show the protobuf message structre as either json or treeview.
is there a way to get the descriptor from a message instance?
i.e. how can I get

```
    //this:
    descriptor = FATHER.Father.Descriptor;
    //from:
    FATHER.Father message = new FATHER.Father();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find static properties on a class using reflection.
If I understand the documentation correctly, every message type has a `MessageDescriptor` in  a static property named `Descriptor`.

This code will try to find that property on any object passed to it.

```
public MessageDescriptor GetDescriptorOfMessageObject(object message) {
    if(message == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(message));
    var typ = message.GetType();

    var descField = typ.GetProperty("Descriptor", BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Static);
    if(descField == null)
        throw new Exception($"Cannot locate descriptor on message of type {typ.FullName}");
    if(descField.PropertyType != typeof(MessageDescriptor))
        throw new Exception($"Field 'Descriptor' on type {typ.FullName} is not a MessageDescriptor");

    var desc = descField.GetValue(null) as MessageDescriptor;   
    return desc;
}
```